# change oracle apex tabular form column width

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, tabular

To change the column width of a tabular form, I have to put the below code into the HTML EXPRESSION field

```
<div style="width:20px;">#COLUMN_NAME#</div>
```

Is there any better way to do this? such as via the CSS on the header of the region?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In form page, if you click on specific column, you will find menu on the right hand side. You can change column width under Appearance section or Advance section. There are places to change the column fields in under that sections.

Under Appearance section you can enter from [width field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekaj2.png).